# How prove this for any postive integer $m$, there exsit complex matrix $B$, such $A=B^m$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ is real symmetric positive definite matrix,

show that:

for any postive integer $m$, there exsit complex matrix $B$, such 
$$A=B^m$$

for this I can prove  when $B$ is real matrix,But I can't for complex matrix .Thank you

Comment: Huh? How can you prove this when $B$ is real but not complex? If $B$ is real, it is complex. Do you mean $A$ is complex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $A$ is diagonalizable since $A$ is real-symmetric. That is,
$$
A=P\Lambda P^{-1}
$$
where $P$ is invertible and $\Lambda=\DeclareMathOperator{diag}{diag}\diag(\lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_n)$ where $\lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_n$ are the (not necessarily distinct) eigenvalues of $A$.

Now, $\lambda_i>0$ for $1\leq i\leq n$ since $A$ is positive-definite. Hence $A=B^m$ where
$$
B=P\diag(\lambda_1^{1/m},\dotsc,\lambda_n^{1/m})P^{-1}
$$

Comment: this $B$ is complex matrix?

Comment: $B\in M_n(\Bbb R)\subset M_n(\Bbb C)$ so technically yes

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is real and positive definite then there are orthogonal $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ so that:

$A=P^{-1}DP=P^{-1}\underbrace{D^{\frac{1}{m}}\cdot...\cdot D^{\frac{1}{m}}}_{\text{m-times}}P=(P^{-1}D^{\frac{1}{m}}P)^{m}=B^{m}$